# d3: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined in d3.force implementation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I understand that the question has been asked a million times. Yet i am unable to figure out what is the issue. I am trying to replicate the force directed graph as given in the link below
[http://bl.ocks.org/paulovn/9686202][1]
The jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/k8a3dyuL/
I am unable to understand why i am getting this error.

I created a sample json object for which it worked as expected.I am able to establish connection between the nodes.

```
"nodes": [
{
  "index": 0, 
  "links": [
    1,
    2,
    3
    ], 
  "score": 7.35923957824707, 
  "level": 3, 
  "title": "Blood Diamond", 
  "cover": "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/wRamTzV6udKaMXrspxqOuo02zk0.jpg", 
  "label": "Blood Diamond (2006)", 
  "director": "Edward Zwick", 
  "cast": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Djimon Hounsou, Jennifer Connelly, Arnold Vosloo, David Harewood, Jimi Mistry, Michael Sheen, Marius Weyers, Stephen Collins, Ato Essandoh", 
  "year": 2006, 
  "duration": "143 minutes", 
  "genre": "Action, Drama, Adventure, Thriller", 
  "id": 1768448
},
{
  "index": 1, 
  "links": [

  ], 
  "score": 7.812180042266846, 
  "level": 2, 
  "title": "Casablanca", 
  "cover": "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/sm1QVZu5RKe1vXVHZooo4SZyHMx.jpg", 
  "label": "Casablanca (1942)", 
  "director": "Michael Curtiz", 
  "cast": "Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergman, Paul Henreid, Claude Rains, Conrad Veidt, Sydney Greenstreet, Peter Lorre, Madeleine Lebeau, Dooley Wilson, Joy Page", 
  "year": 1942, 
  "duration": "102 minutes", 
  "genre": "Drama, Romance, War, Crime", 
  "id": 1750024
},
{
  "index": 2, 
  "links": [
    0
  ], 
  "score": 7.167639255523682, 
  "level": 2, 
  "title": "Lonely Hearts", 
  "cover": "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/wxsyl5wjobtYhll3rf5nGuC4kBN.jpg", 
  "label": "Lonely Hearts (2006)", 
  "director": "Todd Robinson", 
  "cast": "John Travolta, James Gandolfini, Salma Hayek, Jared Leto, Laura Dern, Dan Byrd, Alice Krige, Dagmara Dominczyk, Bailee Madison", 
  "year": 2006, 
  "duration": "108 minutes", 
  "genre": "Drama, Romance, Thriller, Crime", 
  "id": 1758379
}, 
{
  "index": 3, 
  "links": [
    1
    ], 
  "score": 7.595, 
  "level": 3, 
  "title": "Some Movie", 
  "cover": "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/wRamTzV6udKaMXrspxqOuo02zk0.jpg", 
  "label": "Some Movie", 
  "director": "Edward Zwick", 
  "cast": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Djimon Hounsou, Jennifer Connelly, Arnold Vosloo, David Harewood, Jimi Mistry, Michael Sheen, Marius Weyers, Stephen Collins, Ato Essandoh", 
  "year": 2006, 
  "duration": "143 minutes", 
  "genre": "Action, Drama, Adventure, Thriller", 
  "id": 1768448
}
],
"links": [
{
  "source": 0, 
  "target": 2, 
  "weight": 0.9770450592041016
},
{
  "source": 0, 
  "target": 3, 
  "weight": 0.9770450592041016
},
{
  "source": 1, 
  "target": 1, 
  "weight": 0.9770450592041016
}
]
}
```

Not Working

```
{
"nodes": [{
    "index": 897,
    "links": [22,
    806,
    897],
    "score": "NA",
    "level": 1,
    "title": "Customer position",
    "cover": "comapny name",
    "label": "label",
    "director": "dir",
    "cast": "cast",
    "year": 2000,
    "duration": 2,
    "genre": "NA",
    "id": 897,
    "weight": 1
},
{
    "index": 737,
    "links": [737,
    869],
    "score": "NA",
    "level": 1,
    "title": "Customer position",
    "cover": "comapny name",
    "label": "label",
    "director": "dir",
    "cast": "cast",
    "year": 2000,
    "duration": 2,
    "genre": "NA",
    "id": 737,
    "weight": 1
},
{
    "index": 869,
    "links": [737,
    869],
    "score": "NA",
    "level": 1,
    "title": "Customer position",
    "cover": "comapny name",
    "label": "label",
    "director": "dir",
    "cast": "cast",
    "year": 2000,
    "duration": 2,
    "genre": "NA",
    "id": 869,
    "weight": 1
}],
"links": [
{
    "source": 737,
    "target": 869,
    "weight": 0.9770450592041016
},
{
    "source": 897,
    "target": 806,
    "weight": 0.9770450592041016
},
{
    "source": 897,
    "target": 22,
    "weight": 0.9770450592041016
}
]
```

}

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me (gives me a different error than the one you mention). It sounds like in your other JSON you're referencing nodes somewhere that you don't have.

Comment: Hi lars, are u not able to access fiddle? do u want me to paste the JSON content here? Thanks

Comment: Hi lars, i verified as per ur suggestion and i am able to see all the nodes within nodes and links section..thanks

Comment: Hi all, can anyone please suggest me about next set of steps. Thanks

Comment: As I've said, I'm getting an error in your jsfiddle about something not being defined. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi Lars, is there any way i can share the code? Thanks

Comment: You could fix the fiddle :)

Comment: Hi Lars, Can you try using the fiddle now . Thanks

Comment: Not working -- if you updated it there would be a different URL.

Comment: oh sorry forgot to attach the link http://jsfiddle.net/7ro02tpj/

Comment: I'm getting the same error message as in your first fiddle.

Comment: oh i am so sorry lars.. I am not sure what is goin on with fiddle. can i zip and send the files to your email id?

Comment: You can also try a different site like plnkr. The advantage of posting it here is that other people can help you as well.

Comment: Hi Lars, is this link working for you. http://plnkr.co/edit/6TlfgPS0pJCqLEDagOMn?p=info

Comment: I'm getting lots of errors and a page telling me that my browser isn't compatible with the site. Could you narrow it down to a minimal example that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: Hi Lars, sorry for the delay in response. Since i was feeling unwell i cld not reply back. I just want to know what is the difference between the 2 JSON files. For one the network graph is rendered and for other it is not. What might be the issue? Is there any certain conventions D3 force layout follows while rendering the force layout?

Comment: Not as such, it really depends on the code you're using.

Comment: Oh ok.. As such i have not changed any code. I just replaced the JSON with my JSON. The format of the JSON too is retained. Its a bit bizzare that this is not working..Thanks Lars for ur patience :)